# dataTime datatype converted to string in importing excel file to protege using Celfie Plugin,

Tags: excel, datetime, import, protege

I am working on Protege 5.0 with the plugin Celfie. I have imported an excel sheet which has a column Start_Time (datatype dateTime). When i import the excel sheet into protege, it converts the rows from dateTime format to a string or some other data type. I want to use that column for a data property having the data type DateTime.

I have attached screenshots of both my excel sheet and the celfie tab. Any help would be appreciated.

[Celfie Plugin Tab snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDm8Q.png)

[Excel Sheet snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZsxw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually a formatting issue in Protege. In Excel, date times are stored as floats, with the integer representing the date and the decimals representing the time.

39448 is 01/01/2008 (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252); since the results you're getting in Protege are similar, those seem to be the raw date time values.

You need to convert them in Protege, either by using an informat when you pull them from Excel, or by formatting them in Protege in the same manner that Excel would.

Comment: Any idea on how to convert it in Protege?

Comment: @Anum I'm afraid not, I've never used it. Do you have any idea how dates are stored in Protege?

Comment: No. I am still working on it. Hopefully I will find something soon. Thanks for your help.